# Auto Focus first row first column in ui-grid only once when the grid loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, user-interface

I placed input box with search icon(input group) by using `editableCellTemplate` in `ui-grid`, How do I `autofocus` first row,first cell only once when the `ui-grid` loads

```
var columnDefs = [
    { name: 'Id' ,
      field:'Id',
      editableCellTemplate:'<div class="input-group"> <input type="text" name="relatedpersonId" id="personidtxtboxdivision" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" data-ng-model="row.entity.id" data-ng-keypress="grid.appScope.checkForValue()" data-ng-blur="grid.appScope.getData(row.entity)"/> <div class="input-group-btn postal-search" data-ng-disabled="true"> <button type="button" data-ng-click="grid.appScope.getData(row.entity)" class="btn btntable btn-xs icon-binoculars pull-right btn-default" title={{rs_select}}><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button></div></div>',
    },
    { name: 'name' },
    { name: 'gender' },
    { name: 'salary' }
  ];
```